# How do i show all product info in opencart module?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm new to opencart and i created a module  like latest module in opencart but the difference is the only latest module show latest product and my module is for all product and showing product in random manner. this my module is working fine..but there is a problem occurs for show the actual rating for each product..Now i want to add rating system in my module.
So  i want to know that whta should be the right query of mysql to get all product info like name,description,reviews,ratings,product_id etc..

Answer (score 4):

you haven't shown your approach so its just general pointers

first you load product.php  model in your controller file `$this->load->model('catalog/product');`

then you decide what would be your filters when calling getProducts if you don't give any filters it will return all products in database, lets say you decide no filters then just pass an empty array of data (or don't pass anything at all )

```
$data = array();
```

then you call the function

```
    $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data); //or without $data
```

now you can do something like

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
$this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],

                );
```

now you can use that in your tpl file like

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
some code here
<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

this is the generic way you should use, and its easy too, if you know how that getProducts function takes data out from database and return result see getProducts function in **catalog/model/catalog/product.php**

Comment: Thanks For your valuable reply..but here is my code for database in model->module section->my_module.php and code is

Comment: $query = "select p.product_id, p.image,p.model, p.price, p.sort_order, p.status, p.width, p.height, p.weight_class_id, p.weight, p.quantity, p.tax_class_id, pd.product_id, pd.language_id, pd.name, pd.description, pd.meta_description, pd.meta_keyword, r.rating, r.product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p, " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd, " . DB_PREFIX . "review r where pd.product_id = p.product_id order by RAND() LIMIT " . $value . " "; this is my code but when i use this code sometime it does not show the product and sometime it gives me error.

Comment: @Neeraj use this `(SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r WHERE r.product_id = p.product_id AND r.status = '1' GROUP BY r.product_id) AS rating` in place of `r.rating`